Seleniumを利用してWebページにアクセスして、同時刻に並行して複数の操作をおこなう方法を教えてください。
現在Python + Selenium でスポーツクラブの自動予約プログラムを作成しようとしています。
このスポーツクラブは、毎月特定の日の予約時刻にその日以降の向こう1ヶ月の予約が取れるようになっています。
予約ページにすすんだ後の予約の手順は、

日付を選択する
レッスンを選択する
レッスンスペースを選択する
選択したスペースの予約をおこなう

となっています。
実際の１から３までのコードは以下のとおりです（ログイン、ログアウトは除外してあります）。このコードを実行すると、選んだスポーツクラブの日付、レッスンを指定して、選んだスペースを選択するところまで実行します。
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from time import sleep

# 予約をとる日付（ここを変えながら複数のプロセスを同時に実行したい）
lesson_date_list = ["20250107", "20250114", "20250121", "20250128"]
# 予約をとる時刻
reservation_time = "07:00:00"

# 予約をとる日付のスケジュール一覧ページのURLを設定する。
LESSON_URL_ROOT = 'https://reserve.holiday-sc.jp/reserve/schedule/151/134?filter_datetimes='
# 現状では１日分だけを表示している。
lesson_url = LESSON_URL_ROOT + lesson_date_list[0]
# ↑ 取りたい日付分のウィンドウを表示してそれぞれを同時に動かしたい。

# 予約したいレッスン一覧ページでの要素インデックス（子要素の番号）
lesson_index = 2
# 予約したいレッスンのX-Path
lesson_xpath = f"//div[@class='lessons']/div[{str(lesson_index)}]"

xpath_index = 1
# 予約したいスペースのX-Path
space_xpath = f"//div[@class='y'][1]//span[contains(text(),{str(xpath_index)})]"

## サブルーチン
def show_lesson_list(driver, lesson_url):
    try:
        driver.get(lesson_url)
        sleep(1)

    except Exception as e:
        print('ページ表示で例外が発生しました！', e)

def select_lesson(driver, lesson_xpath):
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

        space_select = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, lesson_xpath)))

        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', space_select)
        # ページ表示を待つためsleep()要
        sleep(1)

    except Exception as e:
        print('レッスン選択で例外が発生しました！', e)

def select_lesson_space(driver, space_xpath):
    try:
        select_space = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, space_xpath)
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', select_space)
        print(f'スペースを選択しました：{str(xpath_index)}')
        sleep(10)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'スペース選択で例外が発生しました！: {e}')


## ここからメインルーチン
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def do_reservation():

    # STEP 1: 指定した日にちのプログラム一覧ページを表示する。
    show_lesson_list(driver, lesson_url)

    # STEP 2: プログラム一覧ページから各レッスンのスペース選択ページに移動する。
    select_lesson(driver, lesson_xpath)

    # STEP 3: 指定のスペースを選択する。
    select_lesson_space(driver, space_xpath)    

# ---------------- scheduleの処理 --------------------
#レッスンを選択して、さらにスペースを選択するようにjob実行を登録
def main_run():
    # 予約処理開始5分前にChhrome Webdriverでウィンドウを開く。
    schedule.every().day.at(reservation_time).do(do_reservation)

    # jobの実行監視、指定時刻になったらjob関数を実行
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

#main_run()

do_reservation()


これらの処理(例えば、毎週火曜日の予約をおこなうとした場合、４つの処理)を同時に実行するための実装をどのようにすればよいのか教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。
開発環境
MacBook Air、macOS/ macOS Big Sur
Python 3.12.1
Selenium 4.19.0

ご自身が途中まで書かれたコードなどはありませんか?
seleniumはWebサイトから要素を特定して実行するので、どのようなWebサイトなのか具体的に分からない場合は回答が難しいと思います

余計なお世話かもですが、一歩間違うとDoS,DDoS攻撃を行っているように見えるので注意した方が良いのでは？ タイミングによっては普通に対話型・手作業で予約しようとしている他の人にとってはズルされているように感じられるでしょう。 あるいはサイトの頑強性などをテストする目的なのかもしれませんが、その場合は商業的な保証とかもかかわるでしょうから、有料サービスを探す方が良いのでは？と思われます。

@ KiYugadgeterさん、コメントありがとうございます。サンプルコードを掲載しました。よろしくお願いいたします。

@ kunifさん、コメントありがとうございます。

やりたい事が本質的に実行可能かどうかを確認した方が良いのでは？ 人間による対話的な手作業で行っていても実行可能な処理なのでしょうか？ その場合どういう順番でどんな指示を行っているのかを細かく書き出して、それをプログラムで再現するようにすれば良いのでは？ 質問の内容だと予約サイト側でそのようなことは行えないようにガードを掛けているか、あるいは複数日の予約状況を(例えば一覧で)表示するだけならサイト側であらかじめ機能を用意しているかもしれません。
